# How to handle POST request to API with multiple JSON objects

Tags: c#, json, api

I have an API that needs to receive multiple invoices through POST request. The incoming JSON looks like below.
My Model looks just like the JSON object.

If I send one invoice, everything works fine and processing works. If I send two invoices (just like the example), I only get the data for the second invoice (I assume that is because that is the last invoice to be deserialized). Is there a way for me to "loop through" the invoices and process each invoice?

I apologize in advance for being a total beginner in C# and API-development

```
{
"Invoices": {
    "Invoice": {
        "SellerParty": {
            "SellerPartyAddress": {
                "Name": "The Company111",
                "AddressLine1": "Street",
                "AddressLine2": "Box 111",
                "ZipCode": "123456",
                "City": "STHLM",
                "Country": "Sweden",
                "CountryCode": "SE"
            },
            "SellerPartyInfo": {
                "WebAddress": "www.thecompany.com",
                "PhoneNumber": "123456789",
                "EmailAddress": "info@thecompany.com"
            },
            "SellerPartyPaymentMeans": {
                "IBAN": "123455670",
                "BICSWIFT": "000000000000",
                "BankAccount": "1111111111111"
            }
        },
        "BuyerParty": {
            "BuyerPartyAddress": {
                "FirstName": "John",
                "SureName": "Doe",
                "AddressLine1": "6541 Hollywood Blvd",
                "ZipCode": "90028",
                "City": "Los Angeles",
                "Country": "USA",
                "CountryCode": "US"
            },
            "BuyerPartyInfo": {
                "CustomerNumber": "88888888888",
                "MobilePhoneNumber": "55555555555",
                "EmailAddress": "john@doe.com"
            }
        },
        "InvoiceInfo": {
            "IssueDate": "string",
            "DueDate": "string",
            "InvoiceNumber": "string",
            "PaymentTerms": "string",
            "SellerRef": "string",
            "BuyerRef": "string",
            "PaymentRef": "string",
            "Currency": "string",
            "PBSnumber": "string",
            "DebGrNr": "string",
            "Transactions": {
                "TransactionLine": {
                    "ArtNo": "123",
                    "Description": "Something",
                    "QTY": "2",
                    "Unit": "st",
                    "NetPrice": "200",
                    "VATRate": "25",
                    "AmountExVAT": "400"
                }
            },
            "TotalAmoutExVAT": "string",
            "TotalPayableAmount": "string",
            "TotalVAT": {
                "VATSubtotal": {
                    "Percent": "25",
                    "VATAmount": "100",
                    "AmountExVAT": "400"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Invoice": {
        "SellerParty": {
            "SellerPartyAddress": {
                "Name": "The Company222",
                "AddressLine1": "Street",
                "AddressLine2": "Box 111",
                "ZipCode": "123456",
                "City": "STHLM",
                "Country": "Sweden",
                "CountryCode": "SE"
            },
            "SellerPartyInfo": {
                "WebAddress": "www.thecompany.com",
                "PhoneNumber": "123456789",
                "EmailAddress": "info@thecompany.com"
            },
            "SellerPartyPaymentMeans": {
                "IBAN": "123455670",
                "BICSWIFT": "000000000000",
                "BankAccount": "1111111111111"
            }
        },
        "BuyerParty": {
            "BuyerPartyAddress": {
                "FirstName": "Jane",
                "SureName": "Doe",
                "AddressLine1": "6541 Hollywood Blvd",
                "ZipCode": "90028",
                "City": "Los Angeles",
                "Country": "USA",
                "CountryCode": "US"
            },
            "BuyerPartyInfo": {
                "CustomerNumber": "88888888888",
                "MobilePhoneNumber": "55555555555",
                "EmailAddress": "jane@doe.com"
            }
        },
        "InvoiceInfo": {
            "IssueDate": "string",
            "DueDate": "string",
            "InvoiceNumber": "string",
            "PaymentTerms": "string",
            "SellerRef": "string",
            "BuyerRef": "string",
            "PaymentRef": "string",
            "Currency": "string",
            "Transactions": {
                "TransactionLine": {
                    "ArtNo": "123",
                    "Description": "Something",
                    "QTY": "2",
                    "Unit": "st",
                    "NetPrice": "200",
                    "VATRate": "25",
                    "AmountExVAT": "400"
                }
            },
            "TotalAmoutExVAT": "string",
            "TotalPayableAmount": "string",
            "TotalVAT": {
                "VATSubtotal": {
                    "Percent": "25",
                    "VATAmount": "100",
                    "AmountExVAT": "400"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Since you didn't upload a code snippet, I don't now how's your API endpoint looks. If it gets string `Post(string invoices)` you may use `JArray.Parse`  something like: `JArray invoices = JArray.Parse(invoices);

            foreach (var invoice in invoices)
            {
               //do your job
            }`

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple properties with the same name at the same level in a JSON object. In your code you have multiple properties called "Invoice", which is causing a problem.

Having the invoices as a JSON array would solve the issue of invalid JSON. I.e:

```
{
    "Invoices": [
        {
            "SellerParty": {
                "SellerPartyAddress": {
                    "Name": "The Company111",
                    "AddressLine1": "Street",
                    "AddressLine2": "Box 111",
                    "ZipCode": "123456",
                    "City": "STHLM",
                    "Country": "Sweden",
                    "CountryCode": "SE"
                },
                "SellerPartyInfo": {
                    "WebAddress": "www.thecompany.com",
                    "PhoneNumber": "123456789",
                    "EmailAddress": "info@thecompany.com"
                },
                "SellerPartyPaymentMeans": {
                    "IBAN": "123455670",
                    "BICSWIFT": "000000000000",
                    "BankAccount": "1111111111111"
                }
            },
            "BuyerParty": {
                "BuyerPartyAddress": {
                    "FirstName": "John",
                    "SureName": "Doe",
                    "AddressLine1": "6541 Hollywood Blvd",
                    "ZipCode": "90028",
                    "City": "Los Angeles",
                    "Country": "USA",
                    "CountryCode": "US"
                },
                "BuyerPartyInfo": {
                    "CustomerNumber": "88888888888",
                    "MobilePhoneNumber": "55555555555",
                    "EmailAddress": "john@doe.com"
                }
            },
            "InvoiceInfo": {
                "IssueDate": "string",
                "DueDate": "string",
                "InvoiceNumber": "string",
                "PaymentTerms": "string",
                "SellerRef": "string",
                "BuyerRef": "string",
                "PaymentRef": "string",
                "Currency": "string",
                "PBSnumber": "string",
                "DebGrNr": "string",
                "Transactions": {
                    "TransactionLine": {
                        "ArtNo": "123",
                        "Description": "Something",
                        "QTY": "2",
                        "Unit": "st",
                        "NetPrice": "200",
                        "VATRate": "25",
                        "AmountExVAT": "400"
                    }
                },
                "TotalAmoutExVAT": "string",
                "TotalPayableAmount": "string",
                "TotalVAT": {
                    "VATSubtotal": {
                        "Percent": "25",
                        "VATAmount": "100",
                        "AmountExVAT": "400"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "SellerParty": {
                "SellerPartyAddress": {
                    "Name": "The Company222",
                    "AddressLine1": "Street",
                    "AddressLine2": "Box 111",
                    "ZipCode": "123456",
                    "City": "STHLM",
                    "Country": "Sweden",
                    "CountryCode": "SE"
                },
                "SellerPartyInfo": {
                    "WebAddress": "www.thecompany.com",
                    "PhoneNumber": "123456789",
                    "EmailAddress": "info@thecompany.com"
                },
                "SellerPartyPaymentMeans": {
                    "IBAN": "123455670",
                    "BICSWIFT": "000000000000",
                    "BankAccount": "1111111111111"
                }
            },
            "BuyerParty": {
                "BuyerPartyAddress": {
                    "FirstName": "Jane",
                    "SureName": "Doe",
                    "AddressLine1": "6541 Hollywood Blvd",
                    "ZipCode": "90028",
                    "City": "Los Angeles",
                    "Country": "USA",
                    "CountryCode": "US"
                },
                "BuyerPartyInfo": {
                    "CustomerNumber": "88888888888",
                    "MobilePhoneNumber": "55555555555",
                    "EmailAddress": "jane@doe.com"
                }
            },
            "InvoiceInfo": {
                "IssueDate": "string",
                "DueDate": "string",
                "InvoiceNumber": "string",
                "PaymentTerms": "string",
                "SellerRef": "string",
                "BuyerRef": "string",
                "PaymentRef": "string",
                "Currency": "string",
                "Transactions": {
                    "TransactionLine": {
                        "ArtNo": "123",
                        "Description": "Something",
                        "QTY": "2",
                        "Unit": "st",
                        "NetPrice": "200",
                        "VATRate": "25",
                        "AmountExVAT": "400"
                    }
                },
                "TotalAmoutExVAT": "string",
                "TotalPayableAmount": "string",
                "TotalVAT": {
                    "VATSubtotal": {
                        "Percent": "25",
                        "VATAmount": "100",
                        "AmountExVAT": "400"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You would then need to iterate through the items in the array to process each.

P.s. the web site https://jsonlint.com is invaluable in checking if your JSON is valid

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify that the array would fix the invalid json, some more work might be needed on the backend to actually process each array item.